# post request to rest api with json body in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest

Am trying to add comment to issue in my jira application through jira rest api's, am doing it in html/javascript code with json body but while am making the request am getting the following errors

"**errorMessages":["Unexpected character ('Ã' (code 195)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at** "

**{"errorMessages":["Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@7b422cb8; line: 1, column: 159]"]}**

Here is my code, please consider my URL and credentials are correct.I have tried with the same url,credentials and json body in REST Client and am able to add comment to issues in my JIRA, Can any one please tell where am doing wrong?

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Comment JIRA REST API</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addComment() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var commentJson = '{"body" : “adding comment to the task from client side javascript code”}';
   
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  
    xhttp.open("POST", "URL",true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic'+btoa('username:password')); 
    xhttp.send(commentJson);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Adding Comment</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="addComment()">Add Comment</button>
<p id="demo"> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you transferring some data that is not in valid format. This mean you need to use `JSON.Stringify()` or encode the json data in `UTF-8`. Probably `JSON.Stringify()` would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
 var commentJson = '{"body" : “adding comment to the task from client side javascript code”}';
```

...has the wrong kind of double quote marks around the second internal string. Make sure all of the double quote marks are straight, not left or right double quotes, like this:

```
var commentJson = '{"body" : "adding comment to the task from client side javascript code"}';
```

In addition, you might have to make sure your character encoding matches, as whiterabbitj suggested, but first you have to deal with using the wrong quote marks. It looks like you're sending in UTF-8, but the server is treating your data as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: yeah,It's about double quotes and character encoding. Thanks a lot both of you, it worked for me now.